# High Disk I/O on server reboot

Tags: hard-drive, io

A CentOS 5.8 machine has high Disk I/O upon starting up. The processes taking up disk IO are kmirrord, kjournald and pdflush. I have done the performed the following:

1) Mounted the filesystem with noatime parameter.
2) Linux kernel version < 2.6.20 and hence iotop does not report. I enabled block_dump and it suggests that  kmirrord, kjournald and pdflush are extensively reading/writing to disk.

Server load also goes up with this high disk utilization. This continues for a while (around half an hour) and the the system is then back to normal.

Is there anything else I can check further?

Comment: How high is "high" disk I/O? A freshly booted server does need a few minutes to settle, but half an hour is longer than I would expect...

Comment: The disk I/O is 100% and load goes upto 20-30 (4 cpus). I then slowed down kmirrord action by adding the following in the sysctl.conf so that the disk read/write is not that frequent: 
vm.dirty_ratio = 40
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 1
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 30000

Answer (score 1):

Check with iotop. It works on CentOS/RHEL 5.8 just fine. [See here.](http://pastebin.com/S4ffHi63)

Does this happen with every reboot? A warm-boot?

Is this server on physical hardware? a VPS? A virtual machine?

How long has this been a problem?

Comment: Yes, I have installed iotop and it also suggests that the top running processes utilizing disk I/O are kmirrord/kjournald. 
We had once faced disk I/O issue due to a large run of emails in queue. We manually cleared the queue, stopped sendmail. (Sendmail is set to be off on boot as well). We also mounted the file system with noatime parameter and the issue was gone then. 

However, now we had to reboot the machine and are seeing the disk issues. It is physical server hosted with one local datacenter.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 5.8 is pretty outdated. 5.10 is the current version.

I just looked up the version history of lvm2 on a current 5.10:

> - Mi Jun 26 2013 Peter Rajnoha  - 2.02.88-12
> - Also filter partitions on mpath components if multipath_component_detection=1.
> - Mi Mai 22 2013 Peter Rajnoha  - 2.02.88-11
> - Refuse to init a snapshot merge in lvconvert if there's no kernel support.
> - Remove warning that manual cleanup is needed after mirror up-convert failure.
> - vgimport '--force' now allows users to import VGs with missing PVs.
> - Mirrored log is now fixed before its mirror when double-fault occurs.
> - Allow lvconvert --stripes/stripesize only with --mirrors and --repair.
> - Increase limit for major:minor to 4095:1048575 when using -My option.
> - Di Aug 28 2012 Peter Rajnoha  - 2.02.88-10
> - Improve documention of allocation policies in lvm.8.
> - Do Jul 26 2012 Peter Rajnoha  - 2.02.88-9
> - Fix alloc cling to cling to PVs already found with contiguous policy.
> - Fix cling policy not to behave like normal policy if no previous LV seg.
> - Fix allocation loop not to use later policies when --alloc cling without tags.
> - Append _TO_LVSEG to names of internal A_CONTIGUOUS and A_CLING flags.   Resolves: #821013
> - Fr Mai 25 2012 Milan Broz  - 2.02.88-8
> - Do not print warning for pv_min_size set in range between 512KB and 2MB.
> - Fix division by zero if PV with zero PE count is used during vgcfgrestore.   Resolves: #786009 #820237
> - Fr Jan 20 2012 Milan Broz  - 2.02.88-7
> - Preserve exclusive activation of cluster mirror when converting.   Resolves: #702065
> - Mi Jan 18 2012 Milan Broz  - 2.02.88-6
> - Fix lvm1 format snapshot handling.
> - Make memory lock error message clearer.   Resolves: #758833 #769053
> - Do Dez 01 2011 Milan Broz  - 2.02.88-5
> - Fix mirror log conversion and vgsplit for mirrored logs.
> - Fix dmeventd automatic snapshot extension.   Resolves: #754598 #755762 #754198

So you might be running into known bugs here.